# Aligning <a> links side by side in the header

Tags: css

I would like to align links in the header of my website. For example, the way the links are aligned in the header of this website.  What is the proper css code for me to do so?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in the way you want to do this and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is going to get a lot of down votes because there are already a lot of resources available to help you understand how to do what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Thank you for the code as well. I didn't expect such a quick reply. I learned the first thing about coding less than a month ago. I am self taught. It seemed fun so I practice regularly.  In the header I have different links that take you to other pages internally. the problem is the links are under each other in the header. Obviously, that's ugly. I want them to go across the top of the page.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle based off a really really old project of mine (I wouldn't mind too much of the crazy css I have in there). Perhaps it'll help you out/you'll get a little out of it. https://jsfiddle.net/tgjqp1od/

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
      <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help